# VS2013 Pro: Linker starts before compiler is finished (multiple projects with dependencies)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, dependencies

I can't find anything about this problem:

```
1>------ Erstellen übersprungen: Projekt: gui, Konfiguration: GUI_Debug Win32 ------
1>Für diese Projektmappenkonfiguration wurde kein zu erstellendes Projekt ausgewählt. 
2>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: mainlib, Konfiguration: MAINLIB_Debug x64 ------
3>------ Erstellen übersprungen: Projekt: DebugDefinitionen, Konfiguration: Debug Win32 ------
3>Für diese Projektmappenkonfiguration wurde kein zu erstellendes Projekt ausgewählt. 
4>------ Erstellen übersprungen: Projekt: Unused, Konfiguration: Unused_Debug Win32 ------
4>Für diese Projektmappenkonfiguration wurde kein zu erstellendes Projekt ausgewählt. 
5>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: MainProject, Konfiguration: MainProject_Debug x64 ------
6>------ Erstellen übersprungen: Projekt: interfaces, Konfiguration: Interfaces_Debug Win32 ------
6>Für diese Projektmappenkonfiguration wurde kein zu erstellendes Projekt ausgewählt. 
2>  xmldocument.cpp
5>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: Datei "M:\Main Project\Temp\obj_mainlib\xmldocument.obj" kann nicht geöffnet werden.
2>include\xml\xmldocument.cpp(60): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ')'
========== Erstellen: 0 erfolgreich, 2 fehlerhaft, 5 aktuell, 4 übersprungen ==========
```

This was the output of the solution build
- Visual Studio 2013 Pro Update 4
- minimal rebuild
- use assembly output of referenced libraries

mainlib (2) is referenced (in project settings) by *MainProject* (5), so *mainlib* must build before *MainProject*. But it seems **the linker (5) ist started before compiling of *mainlib* is finished** (linker fails due to missing obj and compiler errors are shown after linker starts). If I start the build a second time, *xmldocument.obj* is already build and linker succeeds.

Has anybody the same issue or a solution? I’m confused and cannot find any wrong project settings.

Thanks!

Comment: Right-click MainProject, Build Dependencies + Project Dependencies, tick "mainlib".

Comment: Wow!
This solved my problem! I didn't even know about this option. Thank you!